# Can I assign an ID/Name to a variable in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, variables

I am trying to give my thread an ID and a name. I have put my current code down below:

```
import threading
import time
import os

FLTXT = open('TXT Files/file.txt', 'w')
name, extension = os.path.splitext("")
print(extension)

def thread_function(textToWrite):
    FLTXT.write(f"{str(textToWrite)}\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    threadsList = list()
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=("Hola",))
    xx = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=("hi",))
    threadsList.append(x)
    threadsList.append(xx)
    x.start()
    xx.start()

    for index, thread in enumerate(threadsList):
        thread.join()
```

I want something like this:

```
x.ID = 1234
x.Name = ThreadName
```

I want it to be something like a class(Or have it be a class)
I have tried to look this up, but I could only find stuff on how to assign values to variables, the basic stuff.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It IS a class object. What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah LMAO I just realized that. Thanks!

Comment: Aside: `textToWrite`  is a `str` already, so `str(textToWrite)` is unneeded, and using a common open file object for multiple threads will have race conditions writing the strings.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yeah I figured that but it said it was an integer. Confused why thats why i put that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could use dictionaries

`threads = { "435" : [ threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=("Hola",)), "Name"] }`

In this example you have a dictionary with an entry made of a key/value pair.
In this case the key "ID" let you access to a list made of two element, the first is your thread object and the second is name.

In this way you can refer a specific thread in your code using is id and still having information on his name

```
thread_object = threads["435"][0]

thread_name = threads["435"][1]
```

This is a good way to call objects in code by my point of view.